# ASP.Net C# AjaxControlToolkit timer malfunction with UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

On a website (using a master page), I use the timer with an UpdatePanel in this way:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="true" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="2"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                        ici mes données
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:Image ID="imgLoader" CssClass="img-loader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icones/loading.gif" Width="25px" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in my code Behind :

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = Sql;
        ListView1.DataBind();
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        imgLoader.Visible = false;
    }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and so I tested the site with iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319), and it works wonderfully
By cons on my web server once I publish the loader circling because I have the following error:

ScriptResource.axd? Uncaught TypeError: n is not a constructor

My server is a Windows 2012R2 with IIS 8.5.9600, I use the application pool with the framework v4
I saw that there could be problem with the framework 2, and must modify a file AjaxTimer.js but this is the framework 4 and I have not the JS file on the server.
Do you have an idea ? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you gone through all the checks around ScriptResource.axd? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloc/2008/12/04/webresource-axd-or-scriptresource-axd-not-working/

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated AjaxControlToolKit from v7 to v16, now developed by DevExpress and now it works!